# how to do a batch Read call in UI5 using oData

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I'm trying to have a batch read call in following manner.

Batch should have:
("/EntitySet", "Get", Filter1),
("/EntitySet", "Get", Filter2),
("/EntitySet", "Get", Filter3)

How to do such a batch call. 
I refered to this blog, but not of much help.
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3957490

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to procedurally do these calls (via [ODataModel#read](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read))?

If you are using regular bindings and then just apply your filters on them, then they will be automatically grouped into a batch (as long as you have enabled the batch mode in the ODataModel's constructor with the `useBatch` parameter -- by default it is enabled).

If you are indeed using ODataModel#read, normally they are also batched together if batch mode is enabled.

If it does not work for some reason, you can always specify the `groupId` when using read, respectively `batchGroupId` when doing binding, to force the requests to be triggered together. You can generate a (pseudo)unique value for this with e.g. [jQuery.sap.uid](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.uid). When you generate this groupId, you should tell the OData model to "defer" its execution by using `setDeferredGroups`. When you are done with your requests, you can "submit" the group using `submitChanges`.

```js
var sGroup = jQuery.sap.uid(),
    oModel = this.getModel();

oModel.setDeferredGroups([sGroup]);

oModel.read("/EntitySet", {groupId: sGroup, filters: ...});
oModel.read("/EntitySet", {groupId: sGroup, filters: ...});
oModel.read("/EntitySet", {groupId: sGroup, filters: ...});

oModel.submitChanges({groupId: sGroup});
```